# Can compilers optimize nested loops?

Tags: c, gcc, memory, compilation, variable-assignment

In some cases, the time it takes to assign a block of memory to a variable is too much and has to be reduced as much as possible for optimization reasons. This most frequently occours when many itterations of the same method have to be made, where memory gets assigned and freed every itteration. Let me explain on an example:

```
while(something){
   int i = 4;
   int b =i*100;
   //...
}
```

Do compilers in this case assign memory before entering the loop as if the variables were declared before the loop, or do they compile assembly code without performing this step and basically compile something "as bad as you wrote it"?
And further, what about nested loops?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, the compiler might simply not assign any memory and consider 400 as a constant, depending on what the rest of the loop body is and depending on what compiler optimisation options you are using. You should  construct a simple runnable example, try out some optimisation flags and analyse the assembly code generated by your compiler.

You can also take a look at [GCC's optimisation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). For instance flags such as `-fgcse-lm` and `-fgcse-sm` can enable some of the behaviour you have described.